How to reduce the size of assets images PNG and SVG files in angular build
I want to reduce/compress the size of assets folder content especially images (PNG, JPEG, SVG).  In the current build its taking the actual size so build size is increased upto 200MB.
How can  reduce the bundle size?

There is no direct tool, because no one knows what quality you want or what kind of compression. U have to do it manually, use a site like this: https://tinypng.com/ or build your own automation tool.
